# Direct limit of a well-founded cofinal branch in iteration tree satisfies the agreement conditions

Tags: solution-verification, proof-explanation, set-theory

Please see **EDIT $2$** below for an updated version of my question.

---

I am studying iteration trees from the "An Outline of Inner Model Theory" article in the handbook and I'm struggling with the last part of the definition. It's on the first paragraph of page $1615$.

At that part of the definition, we are constructing the tree at limit stages according to the game $\mathcal{G}_k(\mathcal{M}, \theta)$; so suppose that we are building $T$ and $\langle \mathcal{M}_\alpha, F_\alpha, D, i_{\alpha\beta}\rangle_{\alpha,\beta<\theta}$ according to the rules. Now suppose that $\lambda$ is a limit and player $II$ chooses a branch $b$ of the tree $T$ on $\lambda$ determined thus far. And suppose $b$ is $\in$-cofinal in $\lambda$ and that $b$ is well-founded in the sense that $D\cap b$ is bounded below $\lambda$ and that the direct limit of $\mathcal{C}_0(\mathcal{M}_\beta)$ for $\beta \in b\setminus\sup(D\cap b)$  along the embeddings $i_{\alpha\beta}$ is well-founded. So now we let $\mathcal{M}_\lambda = \underset{\alpha\in b}{\text{dirlim }} \mathcal{M}_\alpha$.

Now my problem is verifying the agreement conditions. I think I have one of the down. So first let $\beta < \lambda$, since $b$ is $\in$-cofinal in $\lambda$, we can see that for sufficiently large $\gamma$ in $b$, $\mathcal{M}_\gamma$ thinks $\text{lh}(F_\beta)$ is a cardinal by the agreement conditions thus far. Also if we take $i_{\gamma\infty}:\mathcal{M}_\gamma\rightarrow\mathcal{M}_\lambda$ be the direct limit embeddings, then by a simple argument, one can see that for sufficiently large $\gamma$, $i_{\gamma\infty}(\text{lh}(F_\beta)) = \text{lh}(F_\beta)$ and since $\text{lh}(F_\beta)$ is a cardinal in large $\mathcal{M}_\gamma$, it must be a cardinal in $\mathcal{M}_\lambda$ too. This proves one of the agreement conditions.

However I don't have a clear idea to prove the other conditon, the fact that if $\beta<\lambda$, then $\mathcal{M}_\beta$ and $\mathcal{M}_\lambda$ agree below $\text{lh}(F_\beta)$. I have tried extending my method for proving the other condition to this one too, but it isn't as straightforward. For example, I can show that for sufficiently large $\gamma$, $i_{\gamma\infty}(J^{\mathcal{M}_\gamma}_{\text{lh}(F_\beta)}) = J^{\mathcal{M}_\lambda}_{\text{lh}(F_\beta)}$, but since we are not working with ordinals I can't finish the argument to show agreement below $\text{lh}(F_\beta)$.

So I have $2$ questions:

(**I**) Is my approach for the first condition correct?

(**II**) How can we show the second agreement condition?

---

**EDIT $1$**:

I noticed that I can probably prove the other condition by the same method, but with one extra assumption that I can't prove yet. First let $\eta < \text{lh}(F_\beta)$, and assume $\gamma$ is large enough, such that $i_{\gamma\infty}(\eta) = \eta$. Now by elementarity and the assumption we made, we have $J^{\mathcal{M}_\lambda}_\eta = J^{\mathcal{M}_\lambda}_{i_{\gamma\infty}(\eta)} = i_{\gamma\infty}(J^{\mathcal{M}_\gamma}_\eta)$. Now I argue that for large enough $\gamma$, $J^{\mathcal{M}_\gamma}_\eta$ and $J^{\mathcal{M}_\lambda}_\eta$ have the same universe: by the direct limit representation, let $[\xi, x] \in J^{\mathcal{M}_\lambda}_\eta$ and also note that by the agreement condition, we may assume that for all larger $\gamma'>\gamma$, $J^{\mathcal{M}_\gamma}_\eta = J^{\mathcal{M}_{\gamma'}}_\eta$ and so take $\xi \ge \gamma$.

So since $\xi$ is larger than $\gamma$, we have: $i_{\xi\infty}(x) = [\xi, x] \in J^{\mathcal{M}_\lambda}_\eta = i_{\xi\infty}(J^{\mathcal{M}_\xi}_\eta)$ and so $x \in J^{\mathcal{M}_\xi}_\eta$. Now comes in the assumption I was talking about:$(*)$ for large enough $\xi$, $i_{\xi\infty}(x) = x$. If we have the previous assumption, then we readily have $J^{\mathcal{M}_\lambda}_\eta\subseteq J^{\mathcal{M}_\xi}_\eta = J^{\mathcal{M}_\gamma}_\eta$; and the other direction follows in a similar fashion. And the same argument shows that the predicates must agree as well by elementarity. And this gives us the second agreement condition.

Now I can add my third question:

$(III)$ Is the above proof correct? If so, how can we prove $(*)$?

---

**EDIT $2$**:

I have noticed that a part of my proof for the first condition has a gap. I had assumed that for large $\gamma$ we have that $i_{\gamma\infty}(\text{lh}(F_\beta)) = \text{lh}(F_\beta)$, by assuming that the map sending each $\xi <\text{lh}(F_\beta)$ to the eventual value of the descending sequence $\langle i_{\eta\infty}(\xi): \eta > \gamma\rangle$, would induce an order-isomorphism between $\text{lh}(F_\beta)$ and $i_{\gamma\infty}(\text{lh}(F_\beta))$. But I can't really why this map is onto.

So to simplify all my questions:

$(IV)$ Why does the direct limit $\mathcal{M}_\lambda$ satisfy the agreement conditions?

Comment: Regarding the first agreement condition: I think your approach in edit 1 is too complicated: There is a bijection $\eta\rightarrow J_\eta^{\mathcal M_\gamma}$ in $\mathcal M_\gamma$. Look at what happens when that is mapped upwards.
To see that eventually $i_{\gamma\infty}(\eta)=\eta$ for $\eta<\mathrm{sup}_{\beta<\lambda} lh(F_\beta)$ show that this supremum is equal to $\liminf_{\gamma\in b}crit(F_\gamma)$. This has to do with how the tree-predecessors are chosen at successor steps.

Comment: @AndreasLietz, thanks! So I think your last suggestion solves my problem with my second edit, and to make sure I understand it correctly, in the liminf, by the $F_\gamma$ you wrote, you meant the extender used to iterate $\mathcal{M}_\gamma$ and not the extender chosen for it in the tree sequence, right? But I still don't know what to do for the first part of your suggestion; can you please elaborate more?

Comment: Yes you are right, I meant the critical points of the embeddings from models on the branch to their successor on the branch...
For the first part: You already know that for $\gamma$ large enough $i_{\gamma\infty}(\eta)=\eta$ and thus $i_{\gamma\infty}(J_\eta^{\mathcal M_\gamma})=J_\eta^{\mathcal M_\lambda}$. Your worry seems to be that this might not be the same as $J_\eta^{\mathcal M_\gamma}$. But if $f:\eta\rightarrow J_\eta^{\mathcal M_\gamma}$ is a bijection in $\mathcal M_\gamma$ then $i_{\gamma\infty}(f)$ is a bijection between $\eta$ and $J_\eta^{\mathcal M_\lambda}$...

Comment: ...(continued) Now you can check that $f=i_{\gamma\infty}(f)$ so indeed $J_{\eta}^{\mathcal M_\gamma}$ is the same as $J_\eta^{\mathcal M_\lambda}$.

Comment: I see, but I don't seem to find a reasonable way to deduce $f=i_{\gamma\infty}(f)$. I guess maybe one has to use the fact that it is (bold-face) $\Sigma_1$, but I can't find a good way of using that. Is there some straightforward way to show that?

Comment: Ah I see! The reason this works is not very specific to the situation here. Technically I am cheating a little bit since I assume we already know that $i_{\gamma\infty}$ restricted to $J_\eta^{\mathcal M_\gamma}$ is the identity. Essentially what I am describing here is the inductive step in the proof that $i_{\gamma\infty}$ is the identity on $J_{crit\ i_{\gamma\infty}}^{\mathcal M_\gamma}$ by $\in$-induction. This is the same argument as showing that $j:V\rightarrow M$ is the identity on $V_{crit\ j}$ if $j$ comes from an extender in $V$.

Comment: Oh, I see. You are totally right. Thanks for clearing things up! Really appreciate it. I would also be happy to accept this as an answer, if you'd choose to post it.